# PHP namespaces and require

Tags: php, namespaces

I need to include several files in a main index.php file.
I'm working with namespaces.

Can I use include/require and make the files use the same namespace as index.php without specifying the namespaces and use statements in each included file?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[PHP namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) are scoped at the file level.

If `a.php` is inside a namespace, and it includes `b.php`, but `b` doesn't specify a namespace, it will *not* adopt the namespace defined in `a`.

Comment: Is there any way to explicitly have the imported symbols adopt the importing file’s namespace?

Comment: Not as far as I know, no.